# Can I check for not equal in a JavaScript switch statement?

Tags: javascript

```
var t = "TEST";
switch(t){
    case !"TEST": /* <- does not work. Can you check if t does NOT contain a string? */
        alert("t != TEST");
    break;
}
```

Can you do this with a switch statement?

Comment: While `switch(true)` and then having cases with logical expressions that evaluate to true/false _works_ in JavaScript … this is not how switch is “meant” to be used. For your simple example, a simple `if` statement would be much better.

Comment: The example is isolated from a much more complex case. Thanks for the comment CBroe!

Comment: Why don't you just use an `if`?

Comment: @subZero Then it shouldn't be included in the switch statement, it will *always* look for true.

Comment: @subZero, I don't know if you checked my answer already but if you did, I just edited it a bit. Please take a look if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 12):

you can also do this:

```
var str = "TEST";

switch (true) {
    case (str !== "TEST") :
        alert("str !== TEST");
        break;
    case (str === null) :
        alert("str is null");
        break;
    default:
        alert("default trigger");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use if. If you prefer switch, use a 'default' case and an if condition there like

```
default:
    if(n == -1){
        //Your code
    }
    break;
```

Comment: If you go this route, you might as well scrap the switch statement in favour of an if else

Answer (score 3):

`case` statement always looks for true. Since you actually want to check if the variable is a string (as I read in the comment in your code), maybe this approach could be right for you:

```
var t = "TEST";
switch(typeof t){
    case "string":
    break;
    default:
        alert("t is not a string");
    break;
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you have more cases in your real code, maybe the code below would do the job?

```
var t = "TEST";
switch(t){
    case t:
        if ("string" != typeof t) {
            alert("t is not a string");
            break;
        }
    case "TEST":
        alert("case 2");
        break;
    case "something_else":
        alert("case 3");
        break;
}
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rz7Sf/. Replace the `t` variable value with an integer and you should see the proper alert.

Answer (score 2):

you can use typeof:

```
<script>
        var t =((typeof "Test")=='string')?true:false;
        switch(t){
            case false:
                alert("t != TEST");
                break;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say:

```
var t = "TEST";
switch(t){
    case "TEST": 
        break;
    default:
        alert("This is the case you want");
        break;
}
```